# How do you define a struct in at&t assembly syntax

Tags: assembly, att

What is the equivalent of this in at&t syntax? I can't seem to find anything via google.

```
struc node
        info: resd  1
        next: resd  1
 endstruc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't anything like it supported by the GNU Assembler. The closest you can come is doing something like:

```
.set note_info, 0
.set note_next, 4
.set note_size, 8
```

You'd use these symbols in statements like the following:

```
head:
    .space note_size

    movl $0, head + note_info
    mov  head + note_next, %esi
    mov  note_next(%esi), %esi
```

Comment: shouldn't note_info be 4

Comment: @sdfsdfsdf It's at offset 0 in the structure.

Comment: @sdfsdfsdf Always more than one way to skin a cat. GAS also has the `.struct` directive to help produce absolute offsets. http://linux.web.cern.ch/linux/scientific4/docs/rhel-as-en-4/struct.html